# What model railroad scale is closest to my 1-inch grid?

Tags: battle-map

I play my tabletop games on a 1-inch grid, where each square represents a 5-foot square. I am looking for some stock scenery I can purchase to make my games a little more interesting and varied.

Some of the best sources for pre-made scenery are model railroad sites, but they use different scales than the mats and the miniatures made for gaming. What scale scenery will fit best in my campaigns?

Comment: I've done enough research to answer my own question, but would love answers (and pictures!) from people who have used model railroad scenery for battle maps before.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**S scale** models will fit best on a standard 1-inch grid, and with your heroic scale 25mm miniatures.

With a 1-inch grid, where each 1-inch square represents a 5-foot square, you are playing at a **1:60** ratio (where 1 real-life inch represents 60 in-game inches.) Your closest model railroad scales are: <sup>([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_transport_modelling_scale_standards#NMRA_Popular_Railway_Scales))</sup>

- *S scale* (aka *3/16" scale*) at **1:64**, or ≈7% smaller
- *O scale* (aka *1/4" scale*) at **1:48**, or ≈25% larger
- *OO scale* (aka *4mm scale*) at **1:76.2**, or ≈27% smaller
- *HO scale* (aka *3.5mm scale*) at **1:87.1**, or ≈45% smaller

If you're looking for items that vary largely in size (trees, rocks, etc.) then any of these scales should look natural. (In fact some sellers lump *S&O* scales together for such items.) If you're looking for something with a much more defined size, such as a bed or a table, you'll probably want to stick with *S scale.*

A note on miniature sizes: the *28mm scale* (aka *heroic scale 25mm*) refers to "the approximate height of a humanoid figure from base of foot to eyeline." <sup>([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_wargaming#Scale), [source](http://theminiaturespage.com/lib/def.mv?id=scale))</sup> Figures tend to vary, however, and historically have leaned on the larger side of the scale, but should remain close to the 1:60 ratio of the 1-inch grid. <sup>([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_figure_%28gaming%29#Scales))</sup>

Comment: ["Don't you mean H0?"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:HO_scale#Number_0_versus_letter_O)

Comment: @IstvanChung **Disclaimer:** I am not a model railroad aficionado and have no preference as to H0 or HO, so just went with how Wikipedia did it. =P

Comment: Sorry, I was joking---just poking fun at the giant and ongoing debate (to which I linked) on the Wikipedia Talk pages.

Comment: http://wargamesandrailroads.blogspot.co.nz/2013/04/s-scale-vs-on30-for-calamity.html